# Rename file in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a situation where I need to deploy different stylesheets to different environments (Dev/Test etc).

Is there a way I can edit the publish artefact so I can do a release pipeline for each environment?

- So I would have a build pipeline that produces theused.css, dev.css,
  test.css
- I would have a release pipeline for Dev & Test
- The dev pipeline would edit the artefact by deleting theused.css then rename
  dev.css to theused.css .. likewise for test

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Meant to add this...

What I ended up doing was the following (with different configs, rather than css, but same idea):

In my app I have configs for Dev, Test & Prod (config.json, config-test.json, config-prod.json)
The first thing the app does is load the config when it runs

I build and deploy to dev

The build folder contains the build files including these config files

I have releases for Test and Prod that do the following:

[image]

Task 1: delete the config.json

Task 2: copy the appropriate config file, e.g. config-test in the test release pipeline, and rename it config.json

Task 3: deploy build files to the appropriate environment with the new config

Comment: This PowerShell step is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is the published artefact in this case a ZIP file?

Answer (score 0):

If I would want to rename a file I would probably write a bash/powershell script and execute it as a task in the pipeline.

- [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops)
- [Power Shell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)

Specifically in your case I would copy/rename the dev.css/test.css to theused.css during the deployment step.
I do not know how you deploy but you could either rename the .css before the deployment to an S3 bucket for example or if you deploy on an on premise server copy the file and rename it at the same time.

```
cp /your/dev.css /your/deployed/path/to/theused.css #copying the file
mv /your/dev.css /your/deployed/path/to/theused.css #move/renaming the file
```